# Format per section numbering of figures and tables

Tags: numbering

I'm number figures and tables by section using `\counterwithin`. However, instead of numbering the figures 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, etc., they are getting numbered 11, 12, 21, 22, etc. Is there a way to reinsert the decimal?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.2}
\end{figure}

\section{foo2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) When I compile your MWE the numbering is correct...

Comment: @Phyelype Yes, from all the documentation, it appears that it should be numbering that way (with the decimals) by default. Are you aware of any way to modify the default formatting that I could potentially use to force it?

Comment: It would be best to see that code that is changing the default behavior, rather than trying to run over it. Anyhow, the figure number is, in standard situations, given by the `\thefigure` macro, so you could try `\makeatletter\def\thefigure{\thesection.\@arabic\c@figure}\makeatother`...

Comment: Yes! Using the *amsmath* package as suggested by @HafidBoukhoulda fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\numberwithin{figure}{section}` from the *amsmath* package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,float}

\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}


\section{foo}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.2}
\end{figure}

\section{foo2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The code you provided works well. It looks like your full code modifies the definition of `\thefigure` somewhere in the preamble. You can use `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}` as means to explicitly redefine `\thefigure` which is the representation of the figure label when it is typeset by LaTeX. Here, `section` is the section counter and `figure` is the figure counter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 1.2}
\end{figure}

\section{foo2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{Should be 2.2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```